# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an app that allows users to comment on a single "work" (think blog post). The associations in the models are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works  
  has_many :comments


class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :work
```

There's a form on the Works show page that allows users to post a comment:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Post a comment!" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The Works controller is as follows. Note that I'm adding the build comment functionality here so that the form on the Works page functions:

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController
   #before_filter :current_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @works = Work.all
    @comment = @work.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @works }
end
end
def create
    @work = current_user.works.create(params[:work])
    redirect_to current_user
  end

def edit
    @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @work = current_user.works.new
end

def destroy
  @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Work deleted"
  redirect_to current_user
end

 def update
    @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id])
    if @work.update_attributes(params[:work])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @work
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def show 
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @work.comments.build
  @comment.user = current_user
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Work", trackable_id: @work).all
  @comments = @work.comments.order("created_at DESC").where(work_id: @work ).all 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @work }
    end
  end
end
```

And lastly, here is the Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Comment", trackable_id: @comment).all
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment }
  end

  def update
     @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
      flash[:success] = "Comment updated"
      redirect_to @comment
    end
  end

  def create
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @work.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      #flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to @work
    else
      render 'home#index'
    end
  end
  end
end
```

When I attempt to submit a comment using the comment form on the works show view page, I get the following error:

Activerecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#create

Couldn't find Work without an ID

Why can't the application find the Work so that it can associate the comment to it?

**EDIT 1:** 
Thanks to the answers below I edited the comment form:

```
<%= form_for(@work, @comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Post feedback or contribute content
    to this work!" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm still getting the same error after making the change to the form and adding the nested route.

I edited the routes file to include a nest for work comments:

```
    authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'activities#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers, :posts, :comments
    end
  end
  resources :works do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :posts
  resources :activities
  resources :comments
```

Rake routes shows the following for Comments#create:
POST   /comments(.:format)

The POST URL (where the error shows up) is appURL/works/1/comments

Doesn't seem right. What do I need to change? Thank you so much for the help so far!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form needs to be `form_for([@work, @comment])` so that Rails knows to build a URL like `/works/123/comments`. Right now it would just be posting to `/comments`.

Check your `rake routes` to see the route for your CommentsController#create action. You might also need to tweak the controller to read `params[:work_id]` instead of `params[:id]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. You are right - it was posting to /comments without an argument for the Work id. I changed the form but now I'm getting an error on the Work show page (I added it to my question above). My rake route for CommentController create is POST   /comments(.:format)

Comment: I added a nested route but the routing still doesn't seem right. The POST URL is now appURL/works/1/comments.

Comment: that looks like a correct route. The output of `rake routes` will probably tell you that your route is now `/works/:work_id/comments` - means you should look up the Work in your Comments#create action by `params[:work_id]`.

Answer (score 1):

The view helper `form_for(@comment)` will post to '/comments' by default. You can specify a url ([see the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)) that includes the `:id` of the work record. The typical approach is to use `form_for([@work, @comment])` and Rails will do this for you so long as you've set up your routes with comments as a nested resource of work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed the form but now I'm getting an error on the Works show page. I think it has something to do with the routes. I posted the routes code in my answer. Did I not add the nesting properly?

Comment: I added the nested routes and changed the form_for but I'm still getting the same error (no Work id). Changed my question above. What else should I change? I don't think my route looks right.