# How do I get form_for(@example) to work inside my Collections#show when example belongs_to Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, rails-models

this seems like a re-occuring problem for my (probably conceptually), hopefully I can tackle it this time! #stillLearning

Two models. 
A Collection has_many :examples
A Example belongs_to :collection

Collection has a title: string
Example has collection_id: integer, and a description: text

Inside my collection/show, I want to also be able to add an Example via this simple form:

```
<%= form_for(@example) do |e| %>

    <h3><%= e.label :description %></h3>
    <%= e.text_area :description %>
    <%= e.submit %>

<% end %>
```

But I get a NoMethodError...

```
undefined method `description' for #<Collection:0x007fe3c4087898>.
```

I understand that @collection doesn't have :description, so that means I have to create a link between Collection and Example right?

Assuming my guess is correct, I tried:

```
rails g migration AddExampleRefToCollections example:references
```

but got the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "references": syntax error: ALTER TABLE "collections" ADD "example" references/Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954969/rails-3-migrations-adding-reference-column

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting of my post.  Still learning the proper etiquette!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Collection` has many `Examples` then `Example` should be the one referencing `Collection` by id in the database:

```
rails g migration AddCollectionIdToExamples collection_id:integer
```

In CollectionsController#show, make sure you are instancing a new empty example to use in the `form` you are going to use:

```
def show
  #stuff
  @example = @collection.examples.new
```

Comment: Thank you @PabloB. This allowed my form to display in CollectionsController#show.  But now, when I click "create" example, it couldn't find the Collection id in the ExamplesController#create method.  

How do I link up the collection_id to the example when it's not automatically part of the parameters?

Comment: The above bug was solved by this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138353/activerecordrecordnotfound-couldnt-find-without-an-id

Essentially, the routes had to be nested so that collection_id was a part of the parameters.  I now understand routing better! Yes! The feeling of progress!